# Ember serializer override normalizeResponse

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

When I do

```js
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Ember from 'ember';

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
  normalizeResponse: function(modelName???){
    model = modelName;
    }
  });
```

Do I have access to the current model's name in normalizeResponse()?  I get a hash of my data, but it doesn't provide me with the model name I so dearly need to create an acceptable ember-data object with a root-element in the json.

Comment: That method doesn't exist: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPISerializer.html what version of ember-data are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the full [signature](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/json-api-serializer.js#L167) is:

```
normalizeResponse: function(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType, isSignle) {
    // ...
}
```

`primaryModelClass` is a string that represents your model class name.

Comment: Ah yes it is I just went to the code myself.  Sorry for the hasty question!